spring security oAuth2.0
`I'm trying to implement Spring security oAuth2.0 using Reactive(Webflux security).  Getting the below error
Description:
Parameter 0 of method setAuthorizedClientManagerRegistrar in org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebFluxSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration$ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerRegistrar' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.ReactiveOAuth2ClientConfiguration$ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManagerRegistrar' in your configuration.
My config file
@Configuration 
@EnableWebFluxSecurity 
@EnableWebSecurity public class OAuth2ClientSecurityConfig {
@Bean public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception { http.securityMatcher("/api/**").authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated()) .oauth2Client(Customizer.withDefaults()); return http.build();}

@Bean public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager( ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository, ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {
ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider = ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder() .clientCredentials().build();
DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager = new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository); authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider); return authorizedClientManager; }

@Bean public WebClient webClient(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository     clientRegistrations, {ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClients)  { ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations, authorizedClients); return WebClient.builder() .filter(oauth) .build(); }

